# why in react.js documentation (the "tutorial" section) is described the necessity of having a running server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server

Surely I'm ignorant, so, please, have patience with me.

I have a local server on my pc (xamp) and I don't understand what is intended to be the "running server" in react.js documentation, tutorial section [->link to react.js tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)

Can you help me to understand this point?

Comment: It means the thing it links to … at the end of the very first paragraph in that section … and which it marks in bold text so you can't miss it.

Answer (score 2):

In that example the server is acting as a back-end for your react app to talk to. If you are simply doing client-side react development, you do not need a server.

Comment: why would anyone downvote this? it´s not a lot of text, but it´s a valid answer...it would be good to point out the reason so people can improve or fix their answer.

Comment: I agree, consider yourself up-voted to counter the down-vote

Comment: good sportsmanship :) - i will upvote too, because he was actually the first to answer. some second before me. also, he needs the points more than we do ;)

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial shows how to use an API to get data from the server, so you need to start one of the example servers. They already include the API endpoints for the tutorial. There is a link to several server implementations, ready to use: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/

It seems that the PHP Server would be your best bet, just download the repository from github and run it with "php server.php", as it is explained in the github link. Although, i would suggest using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) instead. The JavaScript world makes a lot more sense with Node.js, especially when you try server side react routing later :)

Comment: I use react on my local machine, I mean, I save my file in my localhost folder, so, they are in a web server. I understand that I need of a script (a php file, for example) to manage data, but the question is: do i have to use exactly that files? Can I write a file on my own (if I would be able to do it...)?

Comment: of course you can write your own, but the tutorial code for the client uses a specific api endpoint as far as i can see. so you would have to deal with that in your own server implementation then ;) - for the tutorial, it may be better to just use the server.php instead.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial that you refer to depends on a web server, so that react.js can talk to the server to get/send data. That's the server that the turorial is talking about. It's basically saying "This tutorial needs to talk to a web server to work - so you're going to need a web server".

Does that help?

Comment: But if I use a webserver on my local machine, why i need the server provided by the react tutorial? If I load my files in my localhost folder, do i need of that server files in order to make react work?

Comment: That server script provided by the tutorial fulfills the API requirements of the tutorial. If you don't have this, you'd need to make your own server solution. "Having a server" is not enough - you need your server to be able to respond to the specific requests from the client